# how to get the facebook profile picture and store it in our database using facebook api?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using codeigniter facebook library to access the facebook user detalis. I have already stored email, first name, lastname. But i am using the same library i am not getting the correct profile picture. Please check with the my below code

```
$this->load->library('facebook_new/facebook');
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    if(!empty($user)) {
        try {
            //$uid = $facebook->getUser()
            //$permissions = $this->facebook->api("/me/permissions"); 
            $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture,name,email');
            //print_r($user_profile);exit;
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    } else {
        $this->facebook->destroySession();
    }
```

Once accesssed i am getting the values as

```
    Array
(
[id] => xxxxx
[first_name] => add
[last_name] => adsfasdf
[picture] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [is_silhouette] => 
                [url] => https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/adsfadf/asdfasdfasdfasdfn.jpg?oh=85d5d12f5b7d379dd9d20bb1ecdafeb2&oe=56E638EA&__gda__=asdfasdf
            )

    )

[name] => xxx xxx
[email] => wqerqwer@asdfasdf.com
)
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at the FB API, but  it used to be that you were explicitly *disallowed* from harvesting information via the API and *storing* it on your servers.

Comment: I m getting the picture but not the correct size how  to get the correct size